# How do I upgrade Stripe for TLS 1.2

Tags: python, stripe-payments, tls1.2

I am using the Stripe module for python (via `pip install stripe`), and I get the following error:

```
AuthenticationError: Request req_90h0QUDIec0Ej7: Stripe no longer 
supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS 
connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more about this at 
https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.
```

Following Stripe's docs, they say you should re-install Python (via `brew`) and upgrade to the latest version of the Stripe library (1.37.0 as of this writing). I've done both of these steps, but it doesn't make a difference.

What else am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
You can check the TLS verison running on your server at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

if your result displays TLS version 1.2 as NO then you have to update it as per the server you are running.